# Javascript:import scripts

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is a method to importing scripts from javascript script to another javascript script.

For example,

```
import script.js //obviously it is wrong.
```

Lets say on script 1:

```
function hello(){
  console.log(1+2);
}
```

I would like to use the functions defined in script 1 on script 2.

Therefore, script 2 should have:

```
 hello();
```

And should produce this on the webpage:

```
3
```

I went to research for answers, yet i do not understand the codes. Can someone explain it, step by step?

Comment: Which answers did you look at that you didn't understand?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("body")

Comment: and body.appendChild(script)

Comment: funny how what was obviously wrong a while ago is now borderline right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var script = document.createElement("script");

script.src = "script1.js"; // set the url of script you want

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

body.appendChild(script); // append script to body will load the script and execute it
```

Comment: Thats it! Thanks for explaining too!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is loaded via the `<script>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

For more advanced Javascript loading, you can use RequireJS [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs)

See http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Comment: I mean importing from a javascript to a javascript.

Comment: Sounds like requirejs

Answer (score 0):

You can import it dynamically:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

Comment: if you will create jsFiddle for your code, i'll will help you with it.